# How to make text slide inside a div

Tags: css, css-transitions

```css
#name
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
I am Batman I am BatmanI am Batman I am Batman
</div>
```

I don't know how to explain this but I have contents of name slide inside the `div` with infinite iterations.

This is what I tried but it doesn;t give affect.

`-webkit-iteration: infinite;`

Comment: There is no animation defined in your code....start there. Perhaps search for "CSS Marquee" on Stack Overflow?

Comment: `-webkit-iteration: infinite;` refers to CSS animations based on `@keyframe` rules. Where's yours?

Comment: @connexo It's also not a real property..the correct one would be `animation-iteration-count`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the right idea and that was a great start. What you are looking for is `@keyframes`. With keyframes, you can create a function name and specify the start and end values with `from` and `to` respectively.

The `animation` property is a shorthand for declaring multiple animation properties in one line. It can take among other things

- **animation-name**: In this case, `move`, that we defined in out keyframes function
- **animation-duration**: How long the animation will take. In this case, it will take 2 seconds, to complete the transition
- **animation-iteration-count**: How many times the function will be called. Here, it will continue indefinitely.

Also, keep in mind that it's `animation-iteration-count` instead of `animation-iteration` if you are not doing the shorthand.

**Browser Support**

- Internet Explorer 10+ (Will not work in IE9 or lower)
- Google Chrome: 43+
- Firefox: 16+
- Safari: 9+
- Opera: 30+

**Snippet**

```css
#name {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  animation: move 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  from { margin-left: 0px; }
  to { margin-left: 100px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
I am Batman I am BatmanI am Batman I am Batman
</div>
```